# viewBox directive won't resize my SVG as expected

Tags: svg

This SVG is intended to appear in a 30x30 square, and I've gotten it to look right in this code pen:
https://codepen.io/pgblu/pen/RwrYXXm

HTML

```
<span class="foo">
  <svg height="30" width="30" viewBox="0 0 450 450">
    <g
       id="layer1"
       transform="translate(-2887.5916,-192.36151)"
    >
      <g transform="matrix(1.3580428, 0, 0, 1.3580428, 2065.078, 44.928302)" id="layer2" />
        <path
            transform="matrix(1.1703715, 0, 0, 1.1703715, 1772.3948, -189.9379)"
            d="M 1338.5714, 519.50507 A 192.85715, 192.85715 0 0 1 1145.7142, 712.36221 192.85715, 192.85715 0 0 1 952.85709, 519.50507 192.85715, 192.85715 0 0 1 1145.7142, 326.64792 192.85715, 192.85715 0 0 1 1338.5714, 519.50507 Z"
            id="redCircle001"
            style="fill:#dd0e00;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
        />
        <g transform="matrix(-3.1435529, 0, 0, -3.1435529, 10926.161, -138.49162)">
          <path
              style="fill:#ffffff"  
              d="m2494.1163, -202.23709 l4, 84.92415 l-25.67715, 0 l4, -84.92415 z"
              id="whiteBeam001"
          />
          <circle
              style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
              id="whiteDot001"
              transform="matrix(0.3181114, 0, 0, 0.3181114, 2440.9065, -251.44719)"
              cx="139.73659"
              cy="101.28652"
              r="36.22654"
          />
        </g>
      </g>
  </svg>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.foo {
  border: 1px solid #ffaa22;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

...but I had to trial-and-error the viewBox directive and ended up with "0 0 450 450". I am clearly doing this wrong. Shouldn't the viewBox correspond to the target size, i.e., "0 0 30 30"? Is there something in the SVG code itself that is making the resizing counterintuitive?

Comment: Why is it counter-intuitive. You've got a path that starts at M 1338.5714, 519.50507 and then you apply various transforms to it. What is it you're expecting to happen here?

Comment: I had assumed that a viewBox of 0 0 30 30 would be the right call, since that is my target size. The SVG code was not built by me.

Comment: What you've got is the equivalent of a drawing 30 feet square with a frame that's 30 inches across. Thus plonking your frame on one bit of your canvas won't display much.

Comment: OK. Are you saying the SVG code itself needs to be changed in order to reduce its size to the target of 30px square?

Comment: That's one way, the other easier way is to use a viewBox to allow a drawing of one size to be displayed in an area of a different size. That's what you've done so what's the problem?

Comment: This is how I would do it: 1.I get the bounding box of the layer1: `layer1.getBBox()`. This is returning an SVGRect with the folowing properties:
`height: 451.42901611328125
width: 451.42919921875
x: 2887.591552734375
y: 192.3615264892578` You can delete the transformation of the layer1 and use the following viewBox="x y width height". Alternatively you can keep the transformation and to the x you sum the transformation's x ( 2887.591552734375  -  2887.5916). Do the same for the y